# How to avoid error in textmatrix function in R's LSA package

Tags: r, kaggle, lsa

I'm taking part in [this Kaggle competition](http://www.kaggle.com/c/asap-sas) and I'm wondering if anyone has any familiarity with the ***textmatrix*** function from the [LSA package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lsa/index.html) in R.

Basically, the *textmatrix* function accepts a directory as an argument and it will create a textmatrix using all text files found within the specified directory.

Unfortunately, the *textmatrix* function will throw an error when it comes across a text file that contains zero terms (this can happen if you filter using stop words, for example).

Does anyone know of a simple way to have textmatrix ***ignore*** files that end up with zero terms? Or of a relatively quick way to identify and remove these files?

TIA!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to make it ignore empty files. A sort-of workaround that I have used is to add a  word that was not yet in the corpus to every file.

Advantages:

- every file will have at least one word, so that `textmatrix` does not fail
- the same word in every file will not affect the relevance of individual documents
- you know that the number of words according to the textmatrix is one more than the number of words in the original documents

Disadvantage:

- each file becomes a bit similar to all the others, because they all share one word.

(Note: there may be disadvantages that I haven't thought of.)